# Selenium test stops executing on a file choosing form

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, windows-7

I have a website where user can send his photo to a contest. He clicks to choose file from disk and sends it using Firefox.

I want to test my form with Selenium in C#. I know there is a way to send local file path to input file, but i want to test it including Windows 7 file open dialog.

I've written test, click a button to open file dialog and execute this code to set path to local file inside the File Upload Dialog:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(localFile);
Thread.Sleep(1500);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

It works properly when i test it on my profile on Windows. But i have another profile on Windows where website test is running. So i use my personal profile to use Windows, and tests run on the second profile. When i set the test to be executed on my second profile than it is not executed properly.

When i switch to this profile i see a dialog window and the localFile url is typed into the File Dialog at the very moment when i switched to the profile. It seems like SendWait does not work when i am not active in the profile where test is executed.

So my question is: what to do to make the test handle File Dialog properly on a profile i am not active when test is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically upload works in simpler way with native Selenium support:

- You should find element "input[type='file']
- Call inputFileElement.SendKeys(fullPathToFile)

fullfilePath could be any valid windows path or Network Share

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean that those tests run on another account with another desktop on the same machine, then there is a high chance that the issue is caused by the way [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) (it is used internally by SendKeys) works - it seems to work only on the current active desktop.

I can't find any reliable documentation from MS on that part, but that's logical and [this answer(on a bit different question) says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565714/3745022)

> it's heavily reliant on the underlying Win32 SendInput API. This won't
>   work at all for keyboard input when a desktop is inactive.

Or it may be because of how your testing infrastructure is set (perhaps it is a non-interactive service - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me/ that is not bound to any desktop).

If **current active desktop** is the reason, then the alternatives are:

1. Separate testing machine, probably virtual (it is the best solution from this and other points of view - one should strive to not test anything on its own machine).
2. Try [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530(v=vs.85).aspx) - that should be independent of active desktop issues - you have window handle - you post message to it, though other issues can surface with it.
3. Try [System.Windows.Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx) to directly change the controls (AFAIK it shouldn't use SendInput or the likes).
4. Keyboard driver - perhaps it can overcome such issues, or perhaps not - that should be researched.

Comment: It's current active desktop issue i suppose