# Program to enter password and unlock windows 7, 8, 10

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, authentication

I want to write a program (in C# or C++) that periodically checks if the Windows is locked (Win + L) and unlocks it (of course assuming the program knows the password).

I saw many questions about this but most of them were asked 10+ years ago and were specific to Windows XP or 7 only.

Is there a way that works for Windows 7+ (including Windows 10) ?

Comment: People need this for steam in-home streaming as well: https://steamcommunity.com/groups/homestream/discussions/0/617335934139051123/

Comment: This is the wrong idea. Just stop the system from locking in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. This is one of those things explicitly forbidden for applications to do. The 'lock' activates the Secure Desktop (see [What happens 'behind' the windows lock screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563549/what-happens-behind-the-windows-lock-screen), although note that [the Secure Desktop moniker is overloaded](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-does-the-windows-secure-desktop-mode-work)). This mode is *designed* to prevent being deactivated without user explicitly providing it's credentials. Any 'circumvention' would be, by definition, a bug. For a more detailed explanation, read the topic of [Winlogon and GINA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543(v=vs.85).aspx).

The linked Steam article is a horrid hack, it  simply *deactivates* the timeout locking, overriding the user chosen setting, it has nothing to do with actually exiting from the 'lock' mode.