# win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle) not working in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I'm new to python and coding in general, but I'm building a "jukebox" software that will take an input from the user and open that song in spotify. I've got it working pretty well, but would like it to run without a monitor or mouse input, just the keyboard (like a regular jukebox).

As a result, I need the user input window to be brought to the foreground every time it asks for input. I've defined that process within the function bring_to_front().

```
def bring_to_front():
    global handle
    handle = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0,0,None,r'C:\WINDOWS\py.exe')
    print(handle)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
```

I'm using that function within my program like this:

```
def program():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    site_login()

    while True:
        global handle
        global s
        global new_track
        bring_to_front()
        song_request()
        close_extra_tabs()
        if s == '*':
            restart()
        if s == '':
            print('Song stopped')
        else:
            for x in song_list:
                if x[0] == s:
                    new_track = x[2]
                    play_song()
                    print('Playing your song.')
                    break
                elif x == 'not_found':
                    print('Song not found')
                    error_audio()
                    break
                else:
                    continue
```

The site_login() function opens Chrome and logs in to spotify, thus putting that window on top. The first iteration of bring_to_front() in the while loop successfully puts the input window in the foreground and lets me type in a song code. However, once I've done that for the first time and Chrome has been brought to the foreground again (to open up a song), I get an error message on the second iteration of bring_to_front(). The problem is specifically with win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle). The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Spotify Jukebox\Spotify Jukebox3.py", line 125, in <module>
    program()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Spotify Jukebox\Spotify Jukebox3.py", line 102, in program
    bring_to_front()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Spotify Jukebox\Spotify Jukebox3.py", line 62, in bring_to_front
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')
```

I can't figure out why it works the first time, but won't continue to work after that. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295337/win32gui-setactivewindow-error-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found) article which seems to reference the same problem. The solution says it works if you send an alt key first, but I couldn't figure out how to do that from his example. Like I said, I'm new to all of this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I found one of the weirdest solution to this- before every call of the setWindowForeground, do a virtual press of alt.

I used pyautogui to do that. Insert the following line between two subsequent calls within a single code

`pyautogui.press("alt")`