# pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')

Tags: python

When using this code:

```
handle = win32gui.FindWindow(0, "Notepad")
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle) ## put the window in foreground
```

I get this error:

```
*pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')*
```

Tried to read all the post about this, but none fixes the problem.. any hints ?

Running on windows 10

Comment: Did you check that you get a valid handle?

Comment: Yes, the handle is valid. The program is actually brought to front, the error comes in IDLE prompt after the program is set correctly to front.

Answer (score 1):

See

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56947788/12097913
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503675/12097913

For some reason, you have to press `alt` before setting the foreground.
A simple

```
import win32gui, win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys('%')
```

or

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press("alt")
```

will work.