# Pywinauto find process window and focus it

Tags: python, user-interface, window, pywinauto

My current situation is that I open a process, which opens in a random location (thats how this process works).

I have the process PID so I need to somehow focus this window, and move it to the center of my screen.
Im doing something wrong as I can't even set focus on that window... tried it with different apps and got the same result...

The way I select the window -

```
appl = pywinauto.application.Application()               
appl.connect(process=824)
app_dialog = appl.top_window_()
app_dialog.Minimize()
app_dialog.Maximize()

##app_dialog.SetFocus() ##doesn't work aswell
##pywinauto.win32functions.SetForegroundWindow(app_dialog)## doesn't work
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: That's very interesting. We fixed method set_focus() some time ago. It should work reliably with pywinauto 0.6.2. Which version do you use?

Comment: Im using pywinauto (0.6.2), thanks.

Comment: Does it work with correct `SetForegroundWindow` call?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say why it doesn't work with pywinauto...
Got it to work with win32gui as the answer here- [Python Window Activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090464/python-window-activation)

long yet efficient ;)

Comment: Checked the code from my answer with WireShark and found that it works but `.set_focus()` really doesn't. Going to fix it in 0.6.3. Thanks for reporting the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Method `app_dialog.set_focus()` should work in pywinauto 0.6.2. If not, it might be a bug. Is your application publicly available somehow? I'd like to reproduce it on my side. Are you trying to activate a background window while you have modal dialog on top of it?

Second case is a wrong usage of `SetForegroundWindow(...)`. It should give a handle, but you pass `WindowSpecification` object `app_dialog`. Right way is the following:

```
handle = app_dialog.wrapper_object().handle
pywinauto.win32functions.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed backend="uia" parameters and it supposed to add that param.

appl = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="uia")
appl.connect(process=824)
...

hope this help!