# pywinauto is not working while lock screen

Tags: python

I am using pywinauto for open a application and set the password. It works fine when computer is open. But it is not working while lock screen.
Below code

```
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.SendKeysCtypes import SendKeys
app = Application()
app.Start("F:\MfeEERM.exe")
time.sleep(2)
SendKeys("India@54321")
```

Comment: Can you use pywinauto to unlock the screen?

Comment: @Pitto I can use. But how to unlock the screen using pywinauto

Comment: That was more a question than an affirmation...

Answer (score 2):

It won't work by OS design (automated unlock is impossible from locked PC itself). But you may use one of the workarounds if you want the remote machine to keep unlocked.

1. Remote Desktop window must be not minimized (switch from full screen to windowed mode, run the script and quickly get back to local PC).
2. Use VNC server software on remote machine and VNC client on local PC (instead of Remote Desktop). I used TightVNC for this purpose on my previous job. Disconnection from remote PC keeps the script running! The only problem you may have is a black screen in TightVNC window: you should install video drivers on remote PC then.
3. Don't use `type_keys()` method or `SendKeys()` function as well as `.click_input()` method. They require PC to be unlocked. If the desired UI element is recognized, you may need methods `.send_keys()`, `.send_keystrokes()` (both should work for minimized app window except some special key combinations) or `.set_edit_text()` (the latter is for edit boxes only).

All known recipes are collected in the [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html).