# Is there a way to simulate Windows alt-tabbing?

Tags: python, windows, pynput

I want to create a program which alt tabs into  for example discord, and enters a message to a user.

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard=Controller()
keyboard.press(Key.alt_l)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.alt_l)
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.type('this is a test message.')
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
```

That's what I have currently to simulate alt tabbing, however is it possible to alt tab into a specific program?

Comment: I'd not alt-tab, as that depends on what windows are open and what you used before. Most likely you can find a window by its title or process anyway. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090464/python-window-activation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Window Activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090464/python-window-activation)

Comment: @Robert No that did not help, thank you for trying though!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar using [pywinauto](https://pypi.org/project/pywinauto/0.5.4/), which is a module that allows you to interact with a programs GUIs in a pythonic way.
Example:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")

app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("File->New")
```

You can read more about pywinauto and what it can do in its documentation [here](http://pywinauto.github.io/docs/contents.html#contents-root)

Comment: Hey! Thank you, does this only work with windows apps? Also, how would I use this to set focus onto the discord app?

Comment: Hey, I wont have time today but if you still need help monday I'll set up an example :-)

Comment: Hey @nordmanden I figured it out, you can import a module called pygetwindow and use win=gw.getWindowsWithTitle('application name')[0]
win.activate() and it works fine!