# How to keep system alive in case of inactivity?

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

Is there any way in Python to keep it system active all the time?

Comment: i think you can use some windows api to send messages like 'activate window' to the process.

Comment: can you share those api ?

Answer (score 9):

**Best way For Windows without Python**

copy the below code and save the file as **.ps1** extension

After saving file, Right click on it and select **Run With PowerShell**

```
Clear-Host
Echo "toggling scroll lock"
$WShell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
while ($true) {
$WShell.sendkeys("{SCROLLLOCK}")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
$WShell.sendkeys("{SCROLLLOCK}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 350
}
```

Comment: how to stop the script after a while?

Comment: @yts61: close the powershell

Answer (score 2):

### **one way worked for me on windows**

---

<kbd>Python3</kbd> <kbd>Windows</kbd>

this will keep your windows awake and prevent it from locking/hibernating

```
#Devil
import ctypes
import sys

#use this to reset the status
def display_reset():
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000)
    sys.exit(0)

def display_on():
    print("Always On")
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000002)

display_on()
```

Comment: Could you please refer below thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090464/python-window-activation

Comment: @Devil - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT : it is solved in windows using above method, still looking for the option to do it in ubuntu18

Comment: @Devil - Are you trying the same python script in ubuntu ?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft : No

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Fedora. Just send the main Teams process a SIGUSR1 before the status changes. The script will continue in the background.

```
#!/bin/bash

signal() {
  while sleep 60 ; do
    kill ${1} ${2} || exit 0
  done
}

PID=$(pgrep -f 'teams.*disable-setuid-sandbox')

[ -z "${PID}" ] && {
  echo "${0}: Teams process not found" >&2
  exit 1
}

(signal -SIGUSR1 ${PID}&)&
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Pyautogui library and datetime

Set a loop that will move the mouse and click. Set it to end when an instantiated time variable equals whatever time is applicable. Ctrl/alt/delete when you return to your work station to break the loop

This can effectively keep you active in less than 11 lines of code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### **GUI Application to keep windows active**

---

<kbd>Python3</kbd>

*install library*

```
pip install pywin32
```

*save below code as **`alive.pyw`** file*

```
from ctypes import windll, wintypes, byref, c_uint, sizeof, Structure
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes
import sys
import threading
import time
import win32api
import win32con


stop_threads = True
SET_IDLE_TIME = 40 #in seconds
tm1 = time.time()
value = 0

class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]

def get_idle_duration():
    global value, tm1
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))

    # millis = 4294967 - lastInputInfo.dwTime - windll.kernel32.GetTickCount()
    # print(windll.kernel32.GetTickCount(), lastInputInfo.dwTime, sizeof(lastInputInfo), millis)
    tm2 = time.time() - tm1
    last_idel_time = lastInputInfo.dwTime
    # print()
    if value != last_idel_time:
        value = last_idel_time
        tm2 = time.time() - time.time()
        tm1 = time.time()
    # print("time:", tm1)
    return tm2


def press_key_2():
    global stop_threads, tm1
    while True:
        if not stop_threads:
            break
        idle_time = get_idle_duration() #seconds
        # print(idle_time)
        g = float("{:.2f}".format(idle_time))
        st = str(g) + " / " + str(SET_IDLE_TIME)
        var.set(st)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if idle_time < SET_IDLE_TIME:
            continue

        print("in ideal state pressing cltr")
        win32api.keybd_event(ord('x'), 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0)
        tm1 = time.time()


#---------------- Monitor threads ------------------------------

t1 = threading.Thread(target=press_key_2, name='t1')
t1.daemon = True

#----------------- TK functions ----------------------

def display_on():
    global tk, t1, stop_threads
    stop_threads = True
    print("Always On")
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000002)
    root.iconify()
    t1.start()
    # t2.start()

def display_reset():
    print("quit pressed")
    global stop_threads
    stop_threads = False
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000)
    sys.exit(0)



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x110")
root.title("Devil")
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

var = tk.StringVar()
var_idle = tk.StringVar()

label = tk.Label(frame, textvariable =  var)#, bd = 5, justify = tk.RIGHT, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_idle = tk.Label(frame,textvariable = var_idle)
var_idle.set("Idle Time")
var.set("-")
button = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="Quit",
                   fg="red",
                   command=display_reset)

slogan = tk.Button(frame,
                   text="Always ON",
                   command=display_on)

label_idle.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,padx=15, pady=13)
label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,padx=15, pady=5)

slogan.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=15, pady=5)
button.pack(side=tk.LEFT,padx=15, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetThreadExecutionState(0x80000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are stepping away from the machine, you can mimic activity with Python, moving your mouse to top left and clicking every n seconds, to cancel simply go to the console, and ctrl + c to exit, you have 5 secs between.

`pip3 install pyautogui`

```
import pyautogui, time
def moveToCornerClick(x,y):
    """x,y pixels from top-left"""
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(5)


count = 0
while True:
    moveToCornerClick(50,150) #y=150 click a little lower on left to avoid hitting other windows toolbar
    count+=1
    print(f"iteration: {count}")
```

[pyautogui documentation - cheatsheet](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: can you suggest something, which don't require continuous mouse movement ?

Answer (score -1):

```
//Create Windows Form project in Visual Studio using C#
//Make sure this form is in focus while the project is running

    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace MsTeamsAvailable
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
                var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4);
                var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
                {
                    MyMethod();
                }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
            }
            private void MyMethod()
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use the latest version free trial of Mouse Jiggle - https://www.mousejiggle.org. It works with Teams & Outlook. Try it out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That doesn't work in all cases. Teams has to be interacted with for some (i.e., something clicked on in Teams or a key pressed while Teams is the active window).